# If Else to compare strings always triggers on the "If" line

Tags: vba, string, if-statement, ms-access

I have an If Else which always triggers on the "If" line.

It compares strings from a table and which are pulled with a DLookup. I checked what the DLookup is returning with a textbox. I'm not sure if am comparing the strings well and have tried the "like" keyword.

```vb
Dim CB As Double
Dim Csize As Double
Dim DocCat As String

'CB Loop - Go through all customers in CArray and get the document letter corresponding to the document number in the textbox named SBBox

Dim CArray(1 To 5) As String
CArray(1) = "FF"
CArray(2) = "GG"
CArray(3) = "HH"
CArray(4) = "JJ"
CArray(5) = "DD"

Dim customer As Variant
For Each customer In CArray

    'Get portion from customer table by corresponding the customer name with name in array. 
    Csize = Nz(DLookup("[portion]", "tblCustomer", "[sName] ='" & customer & "'"))

    'get document letter from table customer depending on name from array. The table contaning the DocLetters is named the same as in the array (e.g. FF GG HH and so on)
    DocCat = Nz(DLookup("[DocLetter]", customer, "[Doc Number]= '" & SBBox.Value & "'"))
    'Doc Number contains Strings
   
    'Use the DocCat to categoriez "bad", "good", "great" Letter. Here is my problem. It always tiggers the first "Then" statement even if the letter isn't correct.
    If StrComp(DocCat, "A") Or StrComp(DocCat, "B") Or StrComp(DocCat, "C") Then
        CB = 0
    ElseIf StrComp(DocCat, "E") Or StrComp(DocCat, "F") or Null Then
        CB = 0.3
    Else: CB = 0.7
    End If

    'I have tried the "Like" keyword

    if (DocCat Like "A" = True) or (DocCat Like "B" = True) or (DocCat Like "C" = True) Then
        CB = 0
    ElseIf (DocCat Like "E" = True) or (DocCat Like "F" = True) or Null Then
        CB = 0.3
    Else: CB = 0.7
    EndIf
```

Comment: Here `DocCat = Nz(DLookup("[DocLetter]", customer, "[Doc Number]= '" & SBBox.Value & "'")` the `customer` variable is a variant representing the current element in the `CArray` array variable, rather than the `tblCustomer` table. Should this not be `"tblCustomer"` in the `DLookUp` function?

Comment: Hi. thx for your help. tblCustomer only contains the size of the customer. The Table with the Doc Numbers are named after the customers, thus ```customer``` is not the problem. 
I checked what the DLookup grabs out of the table and it is correct, no problem there. As soon as it goes into the If statement it just triggers the first line

Comment: Ok. But you are using `DLookUp` on an array element that will only be `FF, GG, HH, JJ` or `DD`. `customer` is not a table, it is a single value. Your use of `DLookUp` is treating it as if it were a table. When you set a break point on this line and run the code, what values are you seeing for the variables?

Comment: So, the `DocCat` value returned is always correct. What are some of these values when `StrComp()` comparisons incorrectly lead to `Then`?

Comment: The ```DLookUp``` returns (A or B or C ... H) sofar that is correct. 
You are right that the ```customer``` is not a table, but it is the variable that is swapped with the ```CArray``` values, thus my ```DLookUp``` will be:
```DocCat = Nz(DLookup("[DocLetter]", "FF", "[Doc Number]= '" & SBBox.Value & "'")``` 
and so on....

Answer (score 0):

```
ElseIf StrComp(DocCat, "E") Or StrComp(DocCat, "F") or Null Then
```

You can't use *Null* this way, and `StrComp` returns 0 for a match, so:

```vb
If StrComp(DocCat, "A") = 0 Or StrComp(DocCat, "B") = 0 Or StrComp(DocCat, "C") = 0 Then
    CB = 0
ElseIf StrComp(DocCat, "E") = 0 Or StrComp(DocCat, "F") = 0 or DocCat = "" Then
    CB = 0.3
Else
    CB = 0.7
End If
```

Comment: Thx Gustav. Changed that, but the false triggering still happens.

Comment: OK. See expanded answer, please.